# Applying jQuery in XSLT

Tags: jquery, xslt

I want to apply jQuery in XSLT. My jQuery function is as below:

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
    $('ul', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
}); 

ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I apply this to my below XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="product/auto">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">John</a>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='admin'/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="admin">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=subject>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subject">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="expand">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('subject : ',.)"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried to do it as below; calling jQuery in XSLT and including function in CDATA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    <![CDATA[
                        $('.expand').click(function() {
                            $('ul', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
                        });

                        ul li ul {
                            display: none;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1></h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="product/auto">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <a class="expand">John</a>
             </li>
             <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
         </ul>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="admin">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <a class="expand">Admin</a>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="subject">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <a class="expand">
                     <xsl:value-of select="concat('subject : ',.)"/>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Html gerenrated afer running the page is as below

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li><a class="expand">John</a></li>
>   <ul>
>     <li><a class="expand">Admin</a></li>
>   </ul>
> </ul>
> ```

Moved the style out of Script block as below

> ```
>    <style>
>         ul li ul {
>         display: none;
>         }
>       </style>
>     <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>       <![CDATA[
>          $('.expand').click(function() {
>             $('ul', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
>           });             
>      ]]>
>     </script>
> ```

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you here?  At first glance, you seem to have CSS rules mixed into your script block, which probably isn't helping.  Do you see any JavaScript errors in the browser or do you not even get that far?

Comment: Will you please share me any samples . Click event is not firing with out any error

Comment: Samples of what, exactly?  Sorry, but it's not clear what bit you're struggling with. Does the HTML generated from the XSLT look correct?

Comment: You appear to have CSS within your `script` block, so I'd imagine at the very least you have some syntax errors.

Comment: Please see the HTML geneated after running the page. It looks proper. Tree structure of XML

Comment: Moved the style out of script block but still no sucess. Click event is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but I think the error is your jQuery selector rather than anything to do with the XSLT.  Your `$('ul', $(this).parent())` will try to match a <ul> in the scope of the clicked element's immediate parent, which is only the enclosing <li> element, hence no match.

Try using `closest` instead:

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').toggle();
  });
```

I'm also not sure why you've got `eq(0)` in there either, but I may be missing something.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!  Did you get anywhere with this?